# SQL Server 2005 database engine login failed error?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I installed SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition on Windows xp.

This account exists in administrators role.But I can't login to SQL Server database engine using Windows authentication method or sql server authentication method and I receive this error message:

```
An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to sql server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default setttings sql server does not allow remote connections.(Provider:named Pipes provider,error:40-could not open a connection to sql server)(Microsoft sql server,error:53).
```

But im trying to connect to a local instance in my computer. Also i checked SQL SERVER 2005 surface area>> surface area configuration for services and connections >>which shows error >>No sql server 2005 componenets were found on the specified computer. Anyone can give clues on this issue. Do i need to install any components to make this work? I had selected all the options while installing.

please help me on this..
 I am attaching the summary log of setup herewtih.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 9.00.1399.06 
>   ==============================  OS Version      : Microsoft Windows XP
>   Professional Service Pack 3 (Build 2600)  Time            : Wed Oct 05
>   09:49:21 2011    CHANGEME1 : The current system does not meet the
>   minimum hardware requirements for this SQL Server release. For system
>   requirements, see Hardware and Software Requirements, in the readme
>   file or in SQL Server Books Online. Machine         : CHANGEME1 
>   Product         : Microsoft SQL Server Setup Support Files (English) 
>   Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         : Successful  Log File
>   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_SQLSupport_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   Native Client  Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         :
>   Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_SQLNCLI_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2005 Premier Partner Edition - ENU  Product Version : 8.0.50727.42 
>   Install         : Successful  Log File        : C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_PPESku_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft Office 2003
>   Web Components  Product Version : 11.0.6558.0  Install         :
>   Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_OWC11_1.log
>
> ---
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   2005 Books Online (English)  Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install
>   : Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>
> ### Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_BOL_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   2005 Backward compatibility  Product Version : 8.05.1054  Install
>   : Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_BackwardsCompat_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : MSXML 6.0 Parser 
>   Product Version : 6.00.3883.8  Install         : Successful  Log File 
>   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_MSXML6_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : SQLXML4  Product
>   Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         : Successful  Log File
>   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_SQLXML4_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   2005 Tools  Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         :
>   Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>
> ### Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_Tools.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28SQL.90%29.aspx) you can't install SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition on Windows XP. It's not supported. It seems that you can install client tools, BOL and some legacy tools, but not the database server engine itself.

So to answer your question: the SQL Server engine has very likely not been installed when you run setup, so neither you can connect to it, nor you can start any SQL Server service.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I installed sql server 2005 standard edition which works.

Answer (score 2):

In the third line of your summary log it says: *The current system does not meet the minimum hardware requirements for this SQL Server release*. This add to what @MicSim has said about your operating system compatibility. Hence the SQL engine component has not been installed. You will need to downgrade the SQL edition or upgrade your operating system version to get the SQL engine component installed.

Answer (score 0):

You would have already checked it.

Is the SQL Server service started? You can check it in SQL Server Configuration Manager/Services console.

Comment: There are no items show in this view.. please let me know how to start it? I think its not installed.But im using enterprise edition. Its not packed with the set up?