# SQL Server 2005 database engine login failed error?

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2005 database engine login failed error?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6518/sql-server-2005-database-engine-login-failed-error)

I installed SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition on Windows xp.

This account exists in administrators role.But I can't connect to SQL Server database engine using either Windows authentication method or sql server authentication method and I receive this error message:

```
An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to sql server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default setttings sql server does not allow remote connections.(Provider:named Pipes provider,error:40-could not open a connection to sql server)(Microsoft sql server,error:53).
```

But im trying to connect to a local instance in my computer. Also i checked SQL SERVER 2005 surface area>> surface area configuration for services and connections >>which shows error >>No sql server 2005 components were found on the specified computer. Anyone can give clues on this issue. Do i need to install any components to make this work? I had selected all the options while installing.

Also while configuring i had given the name as shown in the pic. So what should be the value that has to be provided for database engine while configuring? (In express edition its instance name/sqlexpress.)
[image: )]

I am attaching the summary log for reference.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 9.00.1399.06 
>   ==============================  OS Version      : Microsoft Windows XP
>   Professional Service Pack 3 (Build 2600)  Time            : Wed Oct 05
>   09:49:21 2011    CHANGEME1 : The current system does not meet the
>   minimum hardware requirements for this SQL Server release. For system
>   requirements, see Hardware and Software Requirements, in the readme
>   file or in SQL Server Books Online. Machine         : CHANGEME1 
>   Product         : Microsoft SQL Server Setup Support Files (English) 
>   Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         : Successful  Log File
>   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_SQLSupport_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   Native Client  Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         :
>   Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_SQLNCLI_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2005 Premier Partner Edition - ENU  Product Version : 8.0.50727.42 
>   Install         : Successful  Log File        : C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_PPESku_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft Office 2003
>   Web Components  Product Version : 11.0.6558.0  Install         :
>   Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_OWC11_1.log
>
> ---
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   2005 Books Online (English)  Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install
>   : Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>
> ### Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_BOL_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   2005 Backward compatibility  Product Version : 8.05.1054  Install
>   : Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_BackwardsCompat_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : MSXML 6.0 Parser 
>   Product Version : 6.00.3883.8  Install         : Successful  Log File 
>   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_MSXML6_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : SQLXML4  Product
>   Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         : Successful  Log File
>   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup
>
> ### Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_SQLXML4_1.log
>
> Machine         : CHANGEME1  Product         : Microsoft SQL Server
>   2005 Tools  Product Version : 9.00.1399.06  Install         :
>   Successful  Log File        : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>
> ### Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files\SQLSetup0002_CHANGEME1_Tools.log

please help me on this..

Answer (score 0):

So is this a local instance or a remote instance?  If you are remote, ensure that TCP/IP protocol is enabled.  If it is a local instance then Shared Memory should be enough to get onto the database engine.  By the error, though, it looks like you have named pipes disabled...?

Is this the default instance?  If not, and it is a named instance ensure that the SQL Server Browser service is started up.

Comment: this is local instance. any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: @user833985 is this the default instance or is it a named instance?

Comment: I didnt get any message for naming the instance while installing the s/w.So hope its default.